# I'm trying to create a timeseries chart having stacked columns in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'x',
            spacingRight: 20,
            defaultSeriesType: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Job Postings by Distribution'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            },
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Job Postings'
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Dice',
            data: [
                [1327899600000, 7], 
                [1327986000000, 11], 
                [1328072400000, 7]
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Career Builder',
            data: [
                [1327899600000, 7], 
                [1327986000000, 11], 
                [1328072400000, 7]
            ]
        }]
    }

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
})
```

I would like each column for a given time to stack the data from the 'Dice' and Career Builder' distributions. But my chart isn't displaying anything. The first item in data is the milliseconds. The second item is the amount of job postings distributed to either Dice or Career Builder,

Answer (score 6):

The thing missing from your configuration is setting stacking to `'normal'`

```js
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
}
```

Full example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWrsf/)

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example with multiple stacks: https://jsfiddle.net/yvr4kstp/1/

```js
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Multiple stacks bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
        month: '%e. %b',
        year: '%b'
      },
      tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      tickWidth: 1,
      minPadding: 0.5,
      maxPadding: 0.5

    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 's1',
        color: '#CCDD00',
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 11), 32401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 12), 32401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 13), 32401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 14), 32401],
        ],
        stack: 'one',
      },
      {
        name: 's2',
        color: '#55DDFF',
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 11), 42401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 12), 42401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 13), 42401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 14), 42401],
        ],
        stack: 'one',
      },
      {
        name: 's1',
        color: '#CCDD00',
        showInLegend: false,
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 11), 12401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 12), 12401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 13), 12401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 14), 12401],
        ],
        stack: 'two',
      },
      {
        name: 's2',
        color: '#55DDFF',
        showInLegend: false,
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 11), 17401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 12), 17401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 13), 17401],
          [Date.UTC(2012, 6, 14), 17401],
        ],
        stack: 'two',
      },
    ]
  });
});
```